# Bootstrap modal submit doesn't pass the variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple modal login form. When the form closes I want to display the email in a separate div . 
The problem is that the text in the div doesn't change. I debugged the code and it looks like when I step through the text changes, but when it gets out of the submit function it gets changed back. What am I doing wrong? tnx!
Here's the code:

```
 <div class="container">
    <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="testButton">Open modal</button>
    <div id="emailTarget">Email ends up here</div>

    <div class="modal" id="myModal">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Please type some text</h4>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form class="form-signin" id="signIn">
                        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                        <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
                        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
                        <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
                        <div class="checkbox">
                          <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
                          </label>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
<script>
    $("#signIn").submit(function(event) {
       $("#emailTarget").html($("#inputEmail").val());
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Can you include your html code?

Comment: When you submit your form the page will reload and any values in javascript will be lost. You could use server side scripting to repopulate the page with the email from POST info.

Comment: maybe you should try event.preventDefault ?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to POST, just return false:

```
   $('#myModal').modal('hide');
   return false;
```

[Check example](http://plnkr.co/edit/cQZFNxlhI70TiQEqUsIE?p=preview)